# How consistent is image decompression across browsers?

Tags: image-processing

I've always assumed that distortions in jpg compressed images are introduced by the compression process itself and that *de*compression of the same source image would result in the same pixels being produced, regardless of the decompression library being used. I've recently been challenged on this point. I've done some tests and haven't observed variation, but my tests are by no means exhaustive. My research on this topic yields articles that are really above my head so I'm reaching out to the experts. Is it possible for two different decompressors to generate different pixel data if fed the same input jpg?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. In theory.

Short answer: no.

Long answer:

According even to Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) JPEG is a standard for "digital compression and coding of continuous-tone still images". What it means in human language is, that, being standardized, the result of compression and decompression shall be deterministic. Deterministic in terms of pixel data. That's theory however and it is only what they are supposed to do.

2. In practise.

Short answer: in theory yes.

Long answer:

First of all the standard defines a compression method for the jpeg format called DCT. However that's the standard. There are numerous implementations and variations of the compression engine. Still, they shall be producing the same pixel data from one jpeg file. However, due to implementation differences and/or bugs it may happen that the resulting pixel data may be different.

But we are talking here about images displayed in browser. Browsers have a variety of rendering engines. No standard defines how is a browser's rendering engine supposed to render a jpeg image. And that's a possible reason for getting different final pixels from the same image displayed in different web browsers if they are forced to resize the image.

This opinion is neither a result of a wide study on the subject nor experiments, so please correct me if I'm wrong somewhere.

Comment: Summarizing, implementations of the standard may not consistently conform to the standard so it's possible that there is some variation between implementations. Is this right?

Comment: That's one of the possible causes, however slightly unlikely. And as I said the images in web browsers are rendered using various rendering engines which may produce different final results. This is the more probable cause.

Comment: I disagree with most statements. Decompression engines will not produce the same exact values. On the opposite, unless they resize, the "rendering engines" have no reason to alter the pixel values.

Comment: Thank you very much @YvesDaoust. You're right. I'm correcting my answer to not be misleading.

Answer (score 3):

A possible cause of discrepancies is the use of different arithmetics, for optimization reasons or other. This results in different truncation errors and accumulation of errors.

I would never bet for all decoders decoding identically, pixel for pixel. After all, JPEG is lossy, so the decompressed image differs from the original anyway, and there is little concern about reproducibility.

A second source of differences is probably... bugs, or inaccuracies in the implementation. Some can very well go unnoticed.

In fact, I would expect that two different decoders return slightly different images most of the time ! Anyway, many decoders are based on the same open-source codec(s), and it may take a while before you meet a different implementation.